# Dripping question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two taps drip together at exactly 1:00 p.m. One tap then drips again every 68 seconds, while the other tap continues to drip every 72 seconds. At what time will the two taps both drip together again?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If they drip together after $t$ seconds, it must be the case that $t$ is a multiple of both $68$ and $72$. What is the least common multiple of $68$ and $72$?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Perry: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Find the smallest $T$ such  that $T=68 m = 72n$ for some $m,n >0 $.

$\text{lcm} (68,72) = 1224$ (seconds), so the time at which they are the same again is 1pm+1224 seconds, which is 1:20:24pm

Answer (score 1):

LCM of 68 and 72=1224
Therefore, time in minutes=1224/60=20 min 4 seconds
That's why another drip with the two drops together will be at 1:20:4 pm

Answer (score 0):

HINT: if they want to drip at the same time, it needs to be:

72*x mod 68 =0.

72 mod 68 = 4

4 * ? =68

if you solve the "?" you need to multiply the value of "?" with 72.
Then u got the seconds to the next drip together.
transorming to minutes etc should be easy